# determine how wide a scrollview is in custom tableview cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a NIB that contains a `UIView` `chartView` that contains a line chart.  The line chart is represented as a `UIScrollview`.  I want to be able to share the chart but can't seem to determine how wide the content view of the UIScrollview is.

```
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(cell.chartView.frame.size)
    cell.chartView.layer.render(in:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

[image]

The above on only gives me the chart that is the width of the disaply, it should be a lot longer (width).

Thanks

Comment: It would be the `scrollView.contentSize`.. It's frame represents only the visible portion of the scrollView.  Try `(cell.chartView as! UIScrollView).contentSize`

Comment: @Brandon - Thanks for the response.  `chartView` is a subclass of a custom class called `Lineart` which is a  UIView `class LineChart: UIView {` so this suggestion is not possible.  `@IBOutlet weak var chartView: LineChart!`

Comment: `The line chart is represented as a UIScrollview`... Use its `contentSize`.

Comment: I guess I don't know how to get the scollview contentsize through the UITableview cell.  All the I have for the scrollview is an IBOutlet for the UIView LineChart.